# Java : How to enter white space as a value of a LimitedTextField?

Tags: java, user-interface, whitespace, textfield

I'm testing a GUI java application developed by someone else. The problem is in a LimitedTextField component : it's impossible to enter a white space in the LimitedTextField althgough there is no restriction in the source code.

Here is the source code that creates 4 LimetedTextField :

```
 contrainteX = Pattern.compile("[0-9A-z/-?:().,'+{}EspaceCrLf]");

 for (int i = 0; i < ligne.length; i++) {
            ligne[i] = new LimitedTextField(35, contrainteX);
            ligne[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 25));
            gbc2.gridx = incrementGridX2;
            gbc2.gridy = incrementGridY2;
            gbc2.gridheight = gbc2.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc2.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            panChamp50KF2.add(ligne[i], gbc2);
            incrementGridY2++;
        }
```

Please help me to proceed.

Comment: this only happens in this concrete `LimitedTextField` ?

Comment: @JordiCastilla no it happens in all the LimitedTextField of the application :(

Comment: maybe is a feature... *why* you need to put whitespaces?

Comment: cause the user needs to write a sentence in some text fields  and it's not possible in this case

Comment: then this `LimitedTextField` is not the correct object for this case

Comment: what should I use instead of this component then ???

Comment: As long as you are only testing, you should mark test as fail and give it back to developer for a fix...